How to read Excel file in Typescript
I have been having trouble finding a great package to read an Excel file in Typescript. The best package that I have found through my research the exceljs package. However, it does not seem to work. After I run the code snippet below, I continue to get the error Nothing to be done, then my program ends. Please let me know if you guys have any insight/ experience in this (or other packages in typescript), as I do not think this should not be so complicated.
import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';

async function parseExcel(filePath: string): Promise<string[][]> {
  console.log('Parsing Excel file:', filePath);
  const workbook = new Workbook();
  let fileInfo: string[][] = [];

  console.log('Reading Excel file:', filePath);
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filePath);
    console.log('read');
}

last logs:
Reading Excel file: ./violations/Book2.xlsx
Nothing to be done.

